# Issues using HC-06 Bluetooth module with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, hc-06

I recently ordered an HC-06 Bluetooth module for my Arduino Uno, and after watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6E5mP70jaw&t=1s), and many others, I still have been having many issues figuring out how to get it to work, and some questions for how the code receives and reads serial data from my phone.

1. I assume this wiring is correct, right?

   - Rx  > Tx
   - Tx  > Rx
   - Gnd > Gnd
   - Vcc > 3.3V
2. When I sent a command over the Bluetooth terminal app I have, the serial monitor displays that command over and over, I assume that is correct also?
3. How do I read the serial input? I've been using

   ```
   if(Serial.available() > 0)
           phoneInput = (char) Serial.read();
   ```

   and then displaying the value of phoneInput to the serial monitor, but for some reason I can't seem to have it control anything properly (in this case an LED)
4. What datatype is the Serial.read() returning to my variable before I cast char on to it?
5. I get errors uploading the code to the board (avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding), until I remove the pin connected to the Rx on the arduino, is there a cleaner solution to uploading the board without unplugging wires?

Comment: I had follow this tutorial and problem fixed: [Tutorial Configure HC-06 Bluetooth Module using AT Command](https://youtu.be/VveS1MhYYMk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume this wiring is correct, right?
>
> ```
> Rx > Tx
> Tx > Rx
> Gnd > Gnd
> Vcc > 3.3V
> ```

Almost. The Arduino's TX should be reduced to 3.3V using a 10k/20k potential divider.

> How do I read the serial input? I've been using
>
> ```
> if(Serial.available() > 0)
>        phoneInput = (char) Serial.read();
> ```

You should read and digest [this](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/).

> What datatype is the Serial.read() returning to my variable before I cast char on to it?

An integer. It holds either 0-255 representing the ASCII code for a character, or -1 if there is nothing in the buffer to read.

> I get errors uploading the code to the board (avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding), until I remove the pin connected to the Rx on the arduino, is there a cleaner solution to uploading the board without unplugging wires?

That will be because you are using pins 0/1 to communicate with the bluetooth which you can't do because those are used to communicate with the PC.

Comment: I'm away from my computer so I can't test your answers, but thanks so much, your answers were super helpful, but I do have one question; If I shouldn't use pins 0 and 1 as Rx and Tx, what pins should I use?

Comment: Anything else - I assume you're using `SoftwareSerial` - that library is designed to use any pin except 0/1. You use `Serial` for pins 0/1. There seems to be a number of tutorials (videos?) around that show SoftwareSerial being incorrectly used with pins 0/1.